# jQuery AJAX how to pass PHP echo to success parameter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So I was learning ajax and followed some codes I found online but didn't know how to pass the value from the PHP.

so this is my email.php

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);
$email = $_POST['email'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM registration WHERE email = '$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($count == 0) {
  $data = json_encode(0); 
} else {
  $data= json_encode(1);
}

mysqli_close($conn);

return data;
```

and this is my ajax

```
$.ajax({
  url: "email",
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    email: email,
  },
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {
    alert("data: " + data); // I tried this one to check what is in data but it's not the values from the echo in PHP
    if (data == 0) {
      $('#message').html('available');
    } else if (data == 1) {
      $('#message').html('not available');
    }
  }
});
```

Your help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

[!] EDIT [!]

Sorry my problem was different. I have a `template.php` file for the whole HTML and where all my PHP files are included. here is the part:

```
if (isset($_GET["route"])) {
  if ($_GET["route"] == 'home' || $_GET["route"] == 'email' ||) {
    include "modules/".$_GET["route"].".php";
  }
}
```

now the value in `alert(data)` is the whole thing in the `template.php` and the `0` or `1` at the end. what I did to solve this problem is: `data.slice(-1)` lol not a good practice though. so if u have other solutions, I would really appreciate it. thank you!

Comment: Generally speaking, do a console.log(data) instead of alert(data). What does it read?

Comment: @ITgoldman the data is my whole html code

Comment: Maybe you forgot to `die()` after the `echo` . Or you have an error. Try first see if a `<?php echo 1; ?>`  file works and you get data back (1).

Comment: @ITgoldman now i think i got it lol it is because i used a template.php and `include` there all of my PHP files. when I added `die()` it shows the whole HTML and the `0` or `1` at the end haha if I don't include the PHP file, it says error 404. do u know any way on how to get the value from the email.php file only?

Comment: I didn't understand the file structure. But you are already doing ajax to `email.php`. Just don't include there anything that outputs HTML. How does your `email.php` look like?

Comment: my `email.php` includes only those codes from my question. but my `template.php` includes code that looks like this: 
`if(isset($_GET["route"])){
if ($_GET["route"] == 'home' ||
            $_GET["route"] == 'email')`

but it works now! i just added `die()` and changed `console.log(data.slice(-1))` now only the echoed value at the end is being passed lol idk if it's a good practice tho

Comment: lol indeed. it's not a good practice but it works.

Comment: It is a good habit to declare your dataType: "json" or dataType: "text" in your JS... when you declare json it will automatically parse for you if you are echoing json. Depending on your vesion of JS/Jquery it can make a difference in error handling.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make changes to the PHP file

```
$data =  json_encode(0);
```

Then return the encoded data in your PHP file like this:

```
return $data;
```

So whenever you make a request to the file it will have a return type that can be accessed in ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to encode the number. Just pass the number as a string to the echo statement.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);
$email = $_POST['email'];
$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM registration WHERE email = '$email'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($count==0){
     echo "0"; 
    } else{
     echo "1";
    }

    mysqli_close($conn); 

} else {
  echo "1";
}
```

Comment: **Warning!** your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: If you really wanted to, you can replace the parameters in the json_encode statements with a **php** array and on the JS side, use `JSON.parse(data)` and store it in a variable for further use.

Comment: thank you for answering! this one doesnt work because I got a different problem. sorry my bad haha